# Readable unit test - lists of complex objects

Tags: unit-testing, scala

**Goal:** Writing more readable tests.

I have a couple of functions, which basically merge and converts two lists of Datasets together, written using Scala and Spark. Each of these Datasets has a lot of fields inside it. For testing, I'm creating three Datasets: New records, existing records, and expected result.

The problem is, tests are long and hard to read. An example:

```
test("Merging Movies") {

val newMovies: Dataset[ATMMovie] = Seq(
    ATMMovie(
        id = 123L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(1524522274),
        movie_title = Some("New movie from ATM"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2018),
        release_date = Some(1524522000),
        primary_language_id = Some(0),
        distributor_id = Some(0),
        internal_pos_movie_code = Some("P1"),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("ID1"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_last_modified_timestamp = None,
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 0
        ),
   ATMMovie(
        id = 456L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(34567522274L),
        movie_title = Some("Title updated"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2016),
        release_date = Some(1524522000),
        primary_language_id = Some(0),
        distributor_id = Some(0),
        internal_pos_movie_code = Some("Movie2"),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("MovieID2"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_last_modified_timestamp = None,
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 3
        )
    ).toDS

val existingMovies: Dataset[ODSMovie] = Seq(
    ODSMovie(
        movie_row_id = 2L,
        movie_source_id = Some("234"),
        movie_entity_id = 7777L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(1524522000),
        movie_title = Some("Old ODS Movie"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2017),
        release_date = Some(1524522987),
        primary_language_id = Some(1),
        distributor_id = Some(5),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("Movie 1"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_Last_modified_timestamp = Some(1524522666),
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 1
      ),
      ODSMovie(
        movie_row_id = 764L,
        movie_entity_id = 658L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(94567522333L),
        movie_title = Some("Old title"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2016),
        release_date = Some(1524522000),
        primary_language_id = Some(0),
        distributor_id = Some(0),
        movie_source_id = Some("Movie2"),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("MovieID2-old"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_Last_modified_timestamp = None,
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 0
    )
).toDS

val expectedODSMovies: Dataset[ODSMovie] = Seq(
    ODSMovie(
        movie_row_id = 765L,
        movie_source_id = Some("P1"),
        movie_entity_id = 123L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(1524522274),
        movie_title = Some("New movie from ATM"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2018),
        release_date = Some(1524522000),
        primary_language_id = Some(0),
        distributor_id = Some(0),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("ID1"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_Last_modified_timestamp = None,
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 0
    ),
    ODSMovie(
        movie_row_id = 764L,
        movie_entity_id = 456L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(34567522274L),
        movie_title = Some("Title updated"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2016),
        release_date = Some(1524522000),
        primary_language_id = Some(0),
        distributor_id = Some(0),
        movie_source_id = Some("Movie2"),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("MovieID2"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_Last_modified_timestamp = None,
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 3
    ),
        ODSMovie( // Movie we had.
        movie_row_id = 2L,
        movie_source_id = Some("234"),
        movie_entity_id = 7777L,
        utc_insert_timestamp = Some(1524522000),
        movie_title = Some("Old ODS Movie"),
        censor_rating_id = Some(0),
        release_year = Some(2017),
        release_date = Some(1524522987),
        primary_language_id = Some(1),
        distributor_id = Some(5),
        internal_pos_movie_id = Some("Movie 1"),
        temporary = 0,
        utc_Last_modified_timestamp = Some(1524522666),
        force_update = 0,
        utc_last_import_attempt_timestamp = None,
        import_attempts = 1
    )
).toDS
```

As you see, each test is very hard to read and follow. I'm looking to find a better way to write these tests.

**Update:** I don't care about the value of most of the fields. I'm going to test the logic of merging.

Comment: I don't know about Scala syntax, but have you considered migrating data to JSON and parse it from the code instead of having it everything in the code?

Comment: Without seeing the code that performs this "merging" I find it hard to tell what's going on in here. Without understanding what are you testing, it's hard to suggest improvements for the tests.

Comment: My team and I typically find that having a "defaults" file in our API test package to be very useful when writing data-oriented tests. If these domain objects need to be used in future, we can rely on the fact that they're determinstic and centralized.

Comment: You say you don't care about the value of most of the fields. I don't understand that, since when testing the merging of data sets, that's about the only interesting thing: whether each field is mapped and merged correctly.

Comment: Yes, we want to check if `movie_title` in input record is the same as `movie_title` in the expected record. However, we don't care if it's `Avengers: End game` or `Auei3894`.

Answer (score 2):

Our best solution to this was to use a generator-like class or function.

```
val newMovies = DataFrameBuilder().add(1).add(2, movie_id=71)
```

It generates values for fields based on the number we provide. If type is a number, value will become the number itself. If it's a string, value will become name of the field plus the number (e.g. `MOVIE_TITLE 1`). We can also pass custom value for fields.

Another solution was to use a function that takes some of the fields we care about, and fills the rest with constant values. Like, it takes `id` and `utc_insert_timestamp`, and fills everything e